# How to separate people into age buckets, given birth year (SQL)

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2014

Given birth_year and personal_id, I want to create var "age" and then group by personal_id into age buckets (ranges) as of 2018.

What I've attempted:

```
SELECT personal_id, (2018 - birth_year) AS age
FROM mydatabase
WHERE birth_year is not null
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN age between 18 and 24 THEN '18-24'
    WHEN age between 25 and 34 THEN '25-34'
    WHEN age between 35 and 44 THEN '35-44'
    WHEN age between 45 and 54 THEN '45-54'
    WHEN age between 55 and 64 THEN '55-64'
    WHEN age > 64 THEN '65+'
    END
```

I'm getting an error saying "age" is not a column name. I'm assuming the CASE statement may need to be nested, like so:

```
SELECT personal_id
FROM
(SELECT personal_id, (2018 - birth_year) as age,
CASE
    WHEN age between 18 and 24 THEN '18-24'
    WHEN age between 25 and 34 THEN '25-34'
    WHEN age between 35 and 44 THEN '35-44'
    WHEN age between 45 and 54 THEN '45-54'
    WHEN age between 55 and 64 THEN '55-64'
    WHEN age > 64 THEN '65+'
ELSE 0
END AS age_group
FROM mydatabase
).
```

The ideal behind this is the "age" var is created first, then people are bucketed.

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT agegrp, COUNT(*)
FROM mydatabase d CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (2018 - birth_year)) v1(age) CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN v1.age between 18 and 24 THEN '18-24'
                   WHEN v1.age between 25 and 34 THEN '25-34'
                   WHEN v1.age between 35 and 44 THEN '35-44'
                   WHEN v1.age between 45 and 54 THEN '45-54'
                   WHEN v1.age between 55 and 64 THEN '55-64'
                   WHEN v1.age > 64 THEN '65+'
              END)
     ) v(agegrp)
WHERE birth_year is not null
GROUP BY agegrp;
```

I changed your query into an aggregation query so it makes sense.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks! The only edit I made was in the first line, COUNT(distinct(personal_id)) since the DB isn't clean. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

inline alias name is not allowed

```
SELECT personal_id, CASE
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 18 and 24 THEN '18-24'
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 25 and 34 THEN '25-34'
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 35 and 44 THEN '35-44'
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 45 and 54 THEN '45-54'
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 55 and 64 THEN '55-64'
WHEN (2018 - birth_year) > 64 THEN '65+' AS age_grop
FROM mydatabase
WHERE birth_year is not null
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 18 and 24 THEN '18-24'
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 25 and 34 THEN '25-34'
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 35 and 44 THEN '35-44'
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 45 and 54 THEN '45-54'
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) between 55 and 64 THEN '55-64'
    WHEN (2018 - birth_year) > 64 THEN '65+'
    END,personal_id
```